# Can't join objects with different materials

Tags: rendering, materials, objects

I'm trying to join multiple objects with different materials(Ctrl+J). When I join them they disappear in render view.
I was trying to assign materials to different mashes, but it doesn't work!
I just don't know what to do

This is my blender file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w6xj5XGGIMKtyS8n-4XUSqpCFBkTOaAx

There is flower model and 4 materials: green for flower stem, flower leafs and flowers

I joined flower stem,leafs and flowers but it shows only flower stem in render view.

edit: sorry, I forget to pack textures into .blend file

Answer (score 2):

So...
When you want to join multiple objects, be sure that they have UV maps with identical names.
It was not obvious for me.